# Why is $\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \{0, 1\}$ not connected and $\operatorname{int}(\Bbb Q) = \varnothing$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Define $A= [0,1]$ with interior $\operatorname{int}(A) = (0,1)$. I ask the following:

- Why is $\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \{0, 1\}$ is not connected$
- Why is $\operatorname{int}(\Bbb Q) = \varnothing$ is connected?

Comment: What topology are you considering?

Comment: Eight months on this site and you haven’t learned mathjax ;) Why don’t you get started here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @majormaki..yes  i have done edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$\{0,1\} = (U \cap I) \cup (V \cap I)$$ for $$U := (-1/2,1/2) \qquad \text{and} \qquad V := (1/2,3/2)$$ and $I := [0,1]$ is the disjoint union of two open subsets in $\{0,1\}$ and $\varnothing$ is connected by definition.

Comment: Um... $\frac13$ is in $[0,\frac12)\cup(\frac12,1]$ but $\frac13$ is not in $\{0,1\}$. So they are not the same set.

Comment: how $ \empty$  is connected ?   and who  is jack lee?.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, of course! Stupid me was thinking about subspace topology without actually writing it out. Thanks.

Comment: +1: @lomber See my answer for the link to the formal defintion.

Comment: @lomber As I said, by *definition*. A space $X$ is said to be **disconnected** iff it is the disjoint union of two *nonempty* subsets, otherwise, $X$ is said to be **connected**. Hence, $\varnothing$ cannot be written as a nonempty union and thus is connected.

Comment: thanks  a  lots @TheGeekGreek

Comment: @lomber You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

1. Take any two $\delta$-neighbourhood ($\delta < 0.5$) at each point of ${\rm Bd}(A)$ separating ${\rm Bd}(A)$.  Under the subspace topology induced by ${\rm Bd}(A)$, we can easily see that $\{0\} = (-\delta, \delta) \cap {\rm Bd}(A)$  is open in ${\rm Bd}(A)$.  Idem for $\{1\}$.
2. Empty set is connected by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Formal_definition) since it can't even contain one nonempty set.

> A topological space $X$ is said to be *disconnected* if it is the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets. Otherwise, X is said to be *connected*.